# AppleScript find items in list

Tags: applescript

I didn't use AppleScript for a while now and I can't seem to code a script I need

What I'm trying to do:

list1: working day `{"Monday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday"}`
item to find *currentDay* : `set currentDay to weekday of (get current date) as text`

(basically I want to check if I'm working today or not in order to run a another script)

```
set currentDay to weekday of (get current date) as text
set workingdays to {"Monday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday"}
set imworking to false

repeat with a from 1 to length of workingdays
    set theCurrentListItem to item a of workingdays
    if theCurrentListItem = workingdays then
        set imworking to true
    else
        set imworking to false
    end if
end repeat
```

*theCurrentListItem* and *currentDay* = *"Monday"*
so why *if theCurrentListItem = workingdays* is not true

Comment: Assuming the test "if theCurrentListItem = workingdays then" works, I would expect your code to work at least some of the time, specifically on Sundays. In general, if you set your test value _imworking_ to _false_ before entering the loop, why would you ever want to explicitly set it to false again? Further, once you've found that the currentDay equals one of your days in the list, why would you continue checking? Though this is more of an efficiency thing. Anyway, both of these issues are addressed with user3439894's code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> (basically I want to check if I'm working today or not in order to run a another script)

Here is a different way of coding it that works:

*Example* **AppleScript** *code*:

```applescript
set currentDay to weekday of (current date) as text
set workingDays to {"Monday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday"}
set imWorking to false

repeat with thisDay in workingDays
    if contents of thisDay = currentDay then
        set imWorking to true
        exit repeat
    end if
end repeat

if imWorking then
    --  # Do other stuff here.
end if
```

Answer (score 0):

A very simple and quick script to do the test. Just verify that the list of working days contains today.

```
set workingDays to {"Monday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday"}
set imWorking to workingDays contains (weekday of (current date) as text)

if imWorking then
    --  # Do other stuff here.
end if
```

Note to international readers: even if macOS is set to another language than English, you must fill workingDays with the day names in English.

For using day names in your system's language, change the test slightly:

```
set workingDays to {"Lundi", "Vendredi", "Samedi", "Dimanche"}
set imWorking to workingDays contains word 1 of ((current date) as text)
```